# How to set Flyway baseline in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I'm currently setting my baseline version this way:

```
        MigrationVersion baselineVersion = appProperties.flyway.getBaselineVersion();

        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.setBaselineVersion(baselineVersion);
        return flyway;
```

The new baseline version I'm using is 2.

I created 2 test migrations - one with version 1 and another with version 2, but they are both still being migrated, although I only need version 2 to be executed.
In flyway_schema_history table I can see the versions 1 and 2 be applied as they should.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following code:

```java
MigrationVersion baselineVersion = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("2");
```

[Flyway documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/latest/org/flywaydb/core/api/MigrationVersion.html#fromVersion(java.lang.String)):

> Create a MigrationVersion from a version String.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Next time, it would be even better if you also include some reference, if it is available. I added it to your post.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help